# ReferenceError: axios is not defined.. In heroku deployment but not in local

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, axios

I recently deployed an app to heroku. The client side works, I can view my page and navigate it. But when I send any request to the server i get:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: axios is not defined`

In local it all works fine, but for production I changed the URL in my axios requests to match the new Heroku URL.

But for some reason in Heroku production it won't load axios?

https://reviewer-jp.herokuapp.com/ is the link if you wanna see the app and the exact messages.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sql-with-orm-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "express.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node express.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.10.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9"
  }
}
```

Main.js file

```
//  Elements
const movieTitle = document.querySelector('#title');
const movieRuntime = document.querySelector('#runtime');
const movieRating = document.querySelector('#rating');
const movieReview = document.querySelector('#review');
const createMovieBtn = document.querySelector('#create-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close');
const notification = document.querySelector('#notification');
const errorDiv = document.querySelector('#error-div');


// Close notification on click
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {;
  notification.style.display = 'none';
})


// Create movie
createMovieBtn.addEventListener('click', async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // Reset the notification bar to be displayed again
  resetNotification();

  let title = movieTitle.value;
  let runtime = movieRuntime.value;
  let rating = movieRating.value;
  let review = movieReview.value;

  const validMovieCreationHTML = validateHTML(title, runtime, rating, review, e);

  //Checks to see if HTML is valid to be posted.
  if(validMovieCreationHTML) {

    // Extract input values from the form element and send them as a post request
    // Use http://localhost:5000 for development
    await axios.post('https://reviewer-jp.herokuapp.com/movies/create', {
      title,
      runtime,
      rating,
      review
    })
    .then((response) => { 
    // Display movie created notification
    showNotification(response);
    clearInputValues();
    })
    .catch( err => errorDiv.innerHTML = err ); // Display error message
  }
});
```

express.js file

```
'use strict';

const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Create the Express app.
const app = express();

// Enable All CORS Requests
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Setup request body JSON parsing.
app.use(express.json());

// Heroku deployment
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

// Setup a friendly greeting for the root route.
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome, please create a movie instance!',
  });
});

// Add routes.
app.use('/movies', routes);

// Send 404 if no other route matched.
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    message: 'Route Not Found',
  });
});

// Setup a global error handler.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(`Global error handler: ${JSON.stringify(err.stack)}`);

  res.status(500).json({
    message: err.message,
    error: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {} : err,
  });
});

// Set our port.
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

// Start listening on our port.
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express server is listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a0c07254d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"></link>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="notification"> 
    <btn id="close"> Close </btn>
  </div>

  <h1>Reviewer</h1>
   
  <div id="error-div"></div>

  <form autocomplete="on" class="create-movie-form" action="submit">
    <label for="title">Movie Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" alt="Movie title" id="title" placeholder="Movie Title" />
    <label for="runtime">Movie Runtime:</label>
    <input type="text" name="runtime" alt="Movie Runtime" id="runtime" placeholder="Runtime" />
    <label for="rating">Movie Rating (Between 1 and 10):</label>
    <input type="text" name="rating" alt="Movie Rating" id="rating" placeholder="What's your rating for this movie?" />
    <label for="review">Movie Review:</label>
    <textarea name="review" alt="Movie Review" id="review" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Movie review"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="create-btn">Create movie review</button>
  </form>

  <form autocomplete="on" id="get-movies-form" action="submit">
    <label class='search-by-title-label' for="search-for-movie-input">Search by movie title:</label>
    <div class="get-movies-div">
      <input type='search' name="search-for-movie-input" alt="Search input" id='movie-title-to-search-input' placeholder="Search" />
      <button id="get-movie-by-name-btn">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <button id='display-all-movies-btn'>Display All Listings</button>

  <div id='movie-list'></div>

  <script src="../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
  <script src="movies.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this on your app:

```
<script src="../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

but you should use the `CDN` with an url like the one provided in [Here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/axios) or if you use `NPM` as it seems.... import it as a module if you can, like this:

Main.js file

```
//  Elements
const movieTitle = document.querySelector('#title');
const movieRuntime = document.querySelector('#runtime');
const movieRating = document.querySelector('#rating');
const movieReview = document.querySelector('#review');
const createMovieBtn = document.querySelector('#create-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close');
const notification = document.querySelector('#notification');
const errorDiv = document.querySelector('#error-div');


const axios = require('axios');
```

otherwise it will never find the `..node_modules/axios....` folder because it is not accesible from the front end, it is on your server.

Comment: This worked! I couldn't require it because it says require is not defined for the front end. But I used the CDN and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks!